# How to set a variable to = width or height in Python Processing?

Tags: python, processing

I'm new to Python and have the following issue.

Normally, if you want to define a variable with the height, width or width/2 of the window in Jave Processing, you can declare it as follows:

```
int x = width/2;
int y = height/2;
```

However, trying this in Python will throw an error:

```
NameError: name 'width' is not defined
```

Here is my code using Python:

```
class Ball:
    x = width/2
    y = height/2

    def draw(self):
        ellipse(self.x, self.y, 20, 20)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How the interpreter should know what do you mean by width and height?

Comment: @Qiu Please read the tag-info, before you spam a comment. The question is clearly tagged [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info). [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts. [`width`](https://processing.org/reference/width.html) and [`height`](https://processing.org/reference/height.html) are predefined variables.

Comment: @Rabbid76, the exact point of my answer, which, quite funny, has been downvoted.

Comment: @asikorski I didn't dwonvote your answer. Anyway you don't need to import `width` and `height`. The variables are just valid in scope of the processing event function callbacks (e.g. `draw` and  `setup`)

Answer (score -1):

To use any variable you should assign value to it. It's rule for all programming languages. So, you didn't assign value to `width` and `height`

Answer (score -1):

The variable width, height should be defined in class member variable or globally.
For example, it can be set when class is constructed.
Like this.

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x = self.width/2
        self.y = self.height/2

    def draw(self):
        ellipse(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
```

Answer (score -1):

The code you wrote is not a complete `class` definition, you should use the `__init__()` function to initialize the elements in a class when a class variable in initialized.

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.x = width/2
        self.y = height/2

    def draw(self):
        ellipse(self.x, self.y, 20, 20)
```

And

```
class_var = Ball(width,height)
```

to create a class variable

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to point out, that this question is related to Processing where `width` and `height` should be predefined by the framework in the global scope, so answers like "To use any variable you should assign value to it" aren't really helpful.

I don't know much about processing with python, but it may be needed to **import** `width` and `height` variables at the top of the file:

```
from processing import width, height
```

---

Also, my advice would be to use:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self):
        ellipse(self.x, self.y, 20, 20)
```

and in main file of your project:

```
b = Ball(width/2, height/2)
```

since it's more ellegant.